# Vertica partition by week on datetime:TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: database, vertica

How do I partition by week on datetime:TIMESTAMPTZ.

I tried this

```
CREATE TABLE abc(time_stamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL) PARTITION BY EXTRACT (week FROM time_stamp);

ERROR 2552:  Cannot use meta function or non-deterministic function in PARTITION BY expression
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are confident that there will never be a time where you have data from the same week over more than one year, you just need to add the `AT TIME ZONE` part to the `TIMESTAMPTZ` type:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
  date      TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY WEEK(date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
```

Otherwise, I would suggesting adding `YEAR` to the partition clause.

Comment: TimeStamptz with a Z keeping it real in the VERT to the ICA!